# Detecting value changes for validation

Tags: angular, validation, onchange

I have the following model(tournament.model.ts) :

```
export class Tournament {

    constructor(
        private _id: string,
        private _name: string) {}


    @Input()
    setName(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }
}
```

I use the above model in my tournament-form.component.ts to get user inputs. As shown in the code I hope to use the setter to detect changes to the value *"name"*.

I want to validate name and display a validation error below the *name* text box.
Is there a way that I can do this or is there a better way?

Note that this is a template-driven form and this is not for the standard html5 validations. I tried using @Input() as follows on the whole model but it didn't work.

```
export class TournamentFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() private tournament: Tournament;


    @ViewChild('t') t; //reference to the tabbed form
    private pageTitle : string;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you make use of forms in angular like Template or reactive forms

Comment: see the Custom Validators section for template-driven forms here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation - bind name to ngModel and attach a custom validator function uisng a directive

Comment: I could manage input text boxes using custom validators except for a selectize plugin I used here: https://github.com/NicholasAzar/ng-selectize. The validations don't work in this case.

Comment: @RahulSingh I used template based forms

Comment: @Maddy this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) might help

Comment: if I set @Input to the Tournament object, it should detect when changing an attribute right?